# Sounds playing on soundboard changing when phone is locked

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio, avfoundation

I created a tone generator using AVFoundation along with a soundboard (swift). On locking the phone, the soundboard sounds play in the background as expected, but the tones being generated change (getting slightly louder and muddled up). Has anyone come across a similar issue?

Thanks

Comment: which API are you using to generate the tone?

Comment: Both AVFoundation and Foundation - it follows the template here: https://github.com/ooper-shlab/ToneGenerator1.0-Swift